# Cakephp hasOne relations - field not found

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I add this code to my model

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Plain' => array(
        'className' => 'Plain',
        'foreignKey'=> false,
        'conditions'=> 'Plain.id = Stats.id_book',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

when I execute a find all I got Plain.id_book not found.

In the database, field is present and query work.

why?

Stats is current model(the code is inside it). In stats table ther's a column called id_book that correspond to id of Plain table

Comment: You have a column called `id_book` in your Plain table? I think you may want to revisit the documentation on associations, specifically what the `foreignKey` and `conditions` keys do.

Comment: Sorry, i rewrote the code without making a copy paste. I modified it and add additional information.

Comment: Your naming scheme is quite different from what Cake is expecting; if it's a third-party thing that you're stuck with, so be it, it can be worked with. But if it's your own design, you would be much better off following the [conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions), then the `bake` utility would be able to correctly generate this code for you.

Comment: Also, to get the result you expect, given your stated setup, I think you need to set `foreignKey` to `id_book` instead of `false`, and leave `conditions` out entirely; `conditions` is for if you have additional conditions beyond the key to base your query on.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions I came to the conclusion that I posted

Answer (score 0):

Reading documentation, I found the solution.

```
$hasOne
```

is used for one-to-one relationships. In my case the relationship was many to one

It was therefore right to use

```
$ belongsTo = ....
```

[documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)